# Getting a SpringBoot property in a non-Spring class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've got a number of properties defined in my `application.properties` file. These are loaded into a number of different configuration files across the system via `@Configuration`, `@PropertySource`, and `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations.

In addition, I have a library, separate from this system, that has no dependence on Spring (and ideally will stay that way). At some point in the execution of the system, it initializes an instance of a class from this library *via reflection and a no args constructor*. However, in that initialization, I want to get a Spring property and assign it to a local field - however, as I mentioned before, this library class is not spring configured, and is in fact in an entirely different project. How can this be done?

My current solution is that when the property is initialized in the config class, the setter for the property also sets a system property (via `System.setProperty("someProp", propValue)`), and then in the no args constructor of the library class I call `System.getProperty("someProp")`. However, this feels really hacky, particularly the part where I set the variable. Perhaps there is some way to configure SpringBoot to automatically propagate that particular property up to become a System property as well?

My code atm

ServiceConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")
public class ServiceConfig {

  private String serviceUrl;

  public String getServiceUrl() {
    return serviceUrl;
  }

  public void setServiceUrl(String serviceUrl) {
    this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
    System.setProperty("SERVICE_URL", serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

My `application.properties`

```
service.serviceUrl=http://localhost:8000
```

LibraryClass.class

```
public class LibraryClass {
    private final String serviceUrl;

    public LibraryClass() {
        this.serviceUrl = getProperty("OAUTH_SERVICE_URL");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: It sounds `LibraryClass` should be an @Bean, with a constructor that takes a String to set the `serviceUrl`.

Comment: That is grim! Either add it to the ctor and pass it in that way. Or perhaps use an `Introspector` and add a setter.

Comment: @AndrewS Unfortunately, I can't make it a bean because, as I briefly mentioned (I'll edit to highlight it more) the class is instantiated via reflection. The explanation as to why is long and messy and probably worth an entirely different StackOverflow post, but the point is, because I have to instantiate it via reflection, I can't inject the bean where it needs to be.

Comment: Is your `LibraryClass` is editable? If so use @Bean above the class otherwise the solution will be different.

Comment: @FimaTaf LibraryClass is editable, but the project it is a part of has no dependence on Spring. So it can't be annotated with `@Bean`.

Comment: I don't see why you need to annotate the library class at all. Just use an `@Configuration` and declare your library as an `@Bean`. I don't understand the question. I thought you needed to create an instance via reflection, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. But remember - a call to `System.setProperty` is always a mistake, and when you have the flexibility of Spring Boot at your disposal it is doubly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `LibraryClass` has a setter method - in the example below named `setServiceUrl(...)` - to set this configuration property you could add this to your existing `ServiceConfig` configuration class:

```
@Bean
public LibraryClass getLibraryClass(@Value(${"OAUTH_SERVICE_URL"}) String serviceUrl) {
    LibraryClass libraryClass = new LibraryClass();
    libraryClass.setServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
    return libraryClass;
}
```

Other than that - if you cannot modify `LibraryClass` because it's parts of a 3rd party library or so... you could use Spring's `Environment` instance, to read all needed properties that - later - will be accessed inside of the constructor of `LibraryClass` and set them just the way you did as System properties. Also add this to your config class:

```
@Autowired
public void setSystemPropsNeededForLibraryClassConstruction(Environment environment) {
    System.setProperty("serviceUrl", environent.getProperty("serviceUrl"));
}
```

Comment: I've added some italics to my original post to highlight the fact that I can't use this method. For a variety of reasons, the class is only instantiated during execution via reflection.

Comment: Just saw your edit. This may be the solution I need. Also not pretty, but better than mine. I actually had no idea about the Environment bean. Thanks!

Comment: Revoking up vote because of `System.setProperty` - this is always a bad idea and never the solution to anything.